# Can't exclude multiple authors in github search

Tags: github

I'm trying to filter out multiple authors:

```
is:pr is:open -author:Marcono1234 -author:rdmarsh2
```

But only the first filter is applied, is it supported? https://github.com/github/codeql/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+-author%3AMarcono1234+-author%3Ardmarsh2+

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that you are using the full search **at the top left box**, Otherwise, the search syntax will be severely **limited**.

Step1:

[image]

Step2:
[image]

Comment: How did you know this? It's not documented anywhere in github.com ...

Comment: What a "meh" solution. But thank you.